# Redirection url in Adobe Analytics

Tags: javascript, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

I have a simple html page in order to test locally the Adobe Analytics.

I try to implement analytics for url.

I have a simple url with onClick event like this:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" onClick="s.tl(this,'e','youtube')">Youtube</a>
```

Using the official [documentation](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/oms_sc_implement.pdf) at page 223 I found the following variables:

```
s.referrer="https://www.youtube.com/"
s.pageURL="https://www.youtube.com/"
```

I add them to my code but the problem persists again. What can I do in order to fix the server call problem?

Solved using this:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" onClick="s.tl(this,'e','youtube',null,'navigate');return false">Youtube</a>
```

Comment: Can you specify what your problem is? No call to Adobe, the incorrect variables being passed, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set your s.linkInternalFilters correctly you shouldn't need to hard code an exit link for www.youtube.com.

The purpose of this configuration variable is to tell Adobe Analytics which link clicks will be considered internal to your site vs. external link clicks (exits) which take you away from your site (IE www.youtube.com).

If you're looking to count any click on a YT link as an exit you can set your s.linkInternalFilters like this:

```
// s_code or DTM JS config
s.linkInternalFilters ="my-local-URL,javascript:,mailto:,tel:"
```

YT link clicks (exits) will now be tracked automatically.